# Ignore a given subdirectory in every directory when syncing with unison

Tags: unison

I want to sync my `workspace` directory with my external backup HD. The thing is that I use ensime and it generates an `.ensime_cache` subdirectory for every project and I don't want to sync those subdirectories with the backup (it can always be downloaded again if I need to rebuild the project).

How do I tell unison to ignore `.ensime_cache` for every project/subproject (thus with arbitrary directory depth)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple googling brought this up: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore

Comment: Thanks, I had already seen and read that page. Problem is that it does not answer my question. All the examples and explanation given refer to fixed depth subdirectories, and this is not the case in question.

Comment: Doesn't the very first example in that linked documentation work for you?

Answer (score 3):

As roaima points out, the `ignore` setting can be used to ignore any path that *contains* a given keyword, so

```
ignore = Name .ensime_cache
```

should work.